# CodeIgniter Joins taking too long but seperate queries are instant

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am writing a system that has the ability to search a medium sized database checking multiple tables for a search query. Just to give you an idea of the scale of the database:

**Customers Table**

Rows: 13396

**Customer_domains Table**

Rows: 13373

They are the only two tables I am trying to search with this query.

**The Problem**

The issue I am facing is, by using a query that uses `joins` the load time is over 2 minutes to complete the search.

By running two seperate queries and returning the combined result of them is nearly instant.

By running two seperate queries instead of a join I can get the search results in a reasonable timeframe **however** using this method I am unable to correctly implement pagination because there are two seperate queries which I can't apply one limit to.

So it seems the correct way to do this would be using a join, but why does the join take excessively longer than a second query?

**My Code using a join (Takes far too long to execute)**

```
public function search($searchquery)
    {
        $this->db->select()
        ->from('customers')
        ->join('customer_domains', 'customer_domains.customer_id = customers.customer_id')
        ->like('customers.customer_id', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.customer_name', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.business_name', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_1', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_2', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_3', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_4', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.postcode', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.landline', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.mobile', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.email', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customer_domains.domain', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->limit(50);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $result = $query->result();

        return $result;

    }
```

**My code with two separate queries (Unable to paginate)**

```
public function search($searchquery)
    {
        $this->db->select()
        ->from('customers')
        ->like('customers.customer_id', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.customer_name', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.business_name', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_1', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_2', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_3', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.address_line_4', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.postcode', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.landline', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.mobile', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->or_like('customers.email', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->limit(50);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $result = $query->result();

        $this->db->select('')
        ->from('customer_domains')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id = customer_domains.customer_id', 'left')
        ->like('customer_domains.domain', $searchquery, 'both')
        ->limit(50);
        $query_domains = $this->db->get();

        foreach($query_domains->result() as $query_domain){
            array_push($result, $query_domain);
        }

        return $result;

    }
```

Does anybody have another solution to this, or maybe can explain why the preferable join statement takes so much longer than a second query and how to improve this? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use SQL for search. Look up [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).

Comment: Indexes and therefore table structure may be relevant. Did you make an `EXPLAIN` on the seperate queries and the joint query? That may help too. =)

Comment: When having databases that are about 10K+ records, you want to make sure you use the database as it's supposed to. Make sure to have relations set, and use indexes. This should make any kind of query be done in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make you query faster you should add index from the tables

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I think that this answer along with the comments left below are what I was looking for. Thanks for your insight everybody.